# Firebase authentication web for Yahoo INVALID_IDP_RESPONSE error

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

I have integrated Firebase authentication with web sdk. Every other provider other than Yahoo works fine. The OAuth login with Yahoo I get a response that looks like the following:

```
{
"error": {
"code": 400,
"message": "INVALID_IDP_RESPONSE : Remote site 5XX from yahoo.com for CODE_EXCHANGE",
"errors": [
   {
    "message": "INVALID_IDP_RESPONSE : Remote site 5XX from yahoo.com for CODE_EXCHANGE",
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "invalid"
   }
  ]
 }
}
```

Comment: The problem seems to be at Firebase end, as when I got an email in my test Yahoo account that I have logged into the app.

Comment: Related (currently no fix): https://github.com/firebase/firebaseui-web/issues/568#issuecomment-502046982

Comment: In my case I managed to resolve it and the service is working fine in production. In my case the error boiled down to asking appropriate permission while making a request and the OAuth app you setup in Yahoo dashboard also must have the correct permissions setup. I needed user's email so to achieve this I had to do two things 1) In client app provider.addScope('sdpp-w') . 2) While setting up the OAuth app had to explicitly add can read and write profile permission (Kinda scary sounding -- stupid Yahoo)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. To fix it I did 2 things:

1. When you create the Yahoo app - at:
   https://developer.yahoo.com/apps/create/ - you must check this API
   Permission: **Profiles (Social Directory) / Read Public Extended**
2. That permission corresponds to the **sdpp-r** scope, which you must declare on the client:

   ```
   var provider = new firebase.auth.OAuthProvider('yahoo.com');
   provider.addScope('sdpp-r');
   ```

This will give you the email address of the logged-in Yahoo user, as stated here: https://developer.yahoo.com/oauth/social-directory-eol/

Comment: We have tried this email is not retrieved if people have other things on top of their account like on mine it will be some other avatar name I have setup instead of my email

Comment: I will like to verify this. How do I create an avatar on top of my account?

Comment: Well Yahoo used to have a little social media like thing back in the days which is 2002 when I had made my account. This was to hide your actual email in yahoo chat rooms which were very popular. I created my avatar name those days and it still shows up here :D